# How to display a user's note after form submit?

Tags: user-expectation, text, data-display

After a form submission I display the user's submitted data, but I struggle with showing an optional note.

This is how I display it when it wasn't filled:

[image]

And this is how I currently display it with given data:

[image]

This does not only look really bad, it also implies that it's an `input` which is not exactly userfriendly.
It's only suppose is to display the user's data again.

I also tried without the outline, but it looks as bad.

**How can/should I display the user's note to look good and userfriendly?**

Comment: The answer to [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/84715/should-read-only-text-appear-as-plain-text-or-in-a-read-only-textbox/84718) question might come in handy. Also, I don't see why the non-outline version would look bad. It might be helpful to visualize the issue if you add the screenshot of the complete form

Comment: We need more context to answer this question. What other information is displayed along with the note? Who is this note being displayed to? Do you need to display the property if there is no note?... However, if this is just about the visual presentation of the note, you may want to try over on the Graphic Design StackExchange site.

Answer (score 0):

[image: image showing the stack overflow quote style]

I think the design that Stack Exchange uses is good. It clearly differentiates it, and strongly implies the static nature of the content.